# How to request location in iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I want to request location in iOS 7+. I can achieve this in iOS 8+ by using this:

```
locationManager.delegate = self 
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest 
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() 
locationManager.requestLocation()
```

but in iOS 7 I can't use these two line:

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.requestLocation()
```

[image]

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hey! Check this article out
http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

Comment: As I said, I can request location in iOS 8+, but I don't know how to request location in iOS 7.

Answer (score -2):

Create an instance of `CLLocationManager` (preferably in your `AppDelegate`). Hold a strong reference to it.

```
-(void)startLocationService{

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 
}
```

Now implement the delegate method as below.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
                  fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
//Your logic to process the location
}
```